# same phtml on same page in magento commerce

Tags: product-page

I want to add one static block above product details on product description page. So i turned on template path hints. And there are two attribute.phtml on same product page.
[image]

Comment: Some attributes in magneto share the same template file. this is not really something to worry about

Comment: But i added a phtml in that phtml file. And now my phtml file is getting displayed twice.

Comment: That is because that file is shared across multiple elements. not recommended amending that file. if you want to implement something id suggest you add in a new block

Comment: I added a new block and called that block in attribute.phtml. But that block is displaying twice

Comment: Do you want to add your static block above product details (tabbing section) ?